# Use include with variables in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a `layouts` folder in my `resources/views` directory and I have a single file named `header.blade.php` there. The file contains the header of the page and I include the header in each of the page in my application. I have all my required `<head>` tags in there. What I do in the page is:

```
@include("layouts.header");
```

But, I want the title of the header and `css <link> tag` to be dynamic. So, is there a way I can pass variable with `@include()` and access the variable in my `header` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use: `@include('layouts.header', ['some' => 'data'])` and then access the data in the header page with, e.g. `$some`.

Comment: Writing here not to make a new post for the same issue. I am trying the above as described also in Laravel documents, but I get an error page that $some is undefined. I am using laravel 8. What could be wrong?

Comment: @ToroLoco I see you marked this answer as correct but your comment says that this answer didn't resolve the issue. I have the same problem, could you enlighten me on how you fixed it? Thank you